# Performing bitwise operations on arrays of boolean

Tags: php, arrays, bitwise-operators

In PHP is there a nice way of running various tests on an array like this...

```
array(true, false, true, false, false);
```

To say give me the **AND** result of all those elements or the **OR** result?

By nice I meant in built without needing to loop around the structure each time.

Comment: Is this 1:1 copy of a homework assignement, or are you just a teacher and "can't snap out of it"?

Comment: Neither. I don't think it is worded particularly 'homeworky'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `(bool) array_sum($array)` to get the `OR` result, and `(bool) array_product($array)` to get the `AND` result.

This works because of the way PHP treats booleans and integers (zero is `false`, everything else is `true`), as well as how a logical (or bitwise) `OR` can be associated with addition while a logical (or bitwise) `AND` is associated with multiplication.

Comment: +1, clever - I was going to post an answer suggesting `array_reduce` but I won't bother now.

Comment: That is excellent, thanks - I had looked at array_reduce and thought that may have been one way of doing it but BoltClock's answer is great.

Comment: Wouldn't that loose the details on what flags are set?

Comment: @Andy E: Why not? It'll be useful for reference!

Comment: @Mark The array(true, false, true, false, false);  Is a list of 5 flags.  I read it as, depending on the flag/bool setting in the array a different set of code is lunched. By turning the array into a decimal value a 32? switch statements could be used instead of a ton if statements.

Comment: Those flags are hard-coded in this case... if they were variable entries in an array though, array_sum() and array_product() don't change the argument array, that remains intact. And I don't see where "a ton of if statements" is mentioned anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You could [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the array and do a [binary to decimal](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php) on it.
Then you just need to do a [Switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) on the result to do what the different flags represent.

That's because your array of bools is basically a 5 digit binary value.

You might need to pad some leading zeros after the implode to the value 8 digits before converting it to a decimal value as bin2dec is funny like that.